# Detect when the user has changed the order of a sortable table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am currently trying to see if there is a way to detect when the user changes the order of a sortable table. I have the table set up with the code

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="captureTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>elem1</th>
            <th>elem2</th>
            <th>elem3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in capture.railLines track by x.ASSET_PK" ng-click="capture.selectLine(x.ASSET_PK)">
            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td>{{x.elem1}}</td>
            <td>{{x.elem2}}</td>
            <td>{{x.elem3}}</td>
            <td><a ng-click="capture.deleteLine(x.elem1)" href="javascript:void(0);">⛔️</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

where the table is made sortable with `$('tbody').sortable()` in an external JavaScript file. I am aware of the `$scope.$apply(function () {})` call, but I can't seem to find a good place to use it in. Most of my functions are tied to `$scope` and I can't use it in those functions.

**EDIT:** I'm not using sortable to actually sort the elements, rather I'm using it so that the user can rearrange the rows by clicking and dragging them around.

Comment: You're better off using an AngularJS implementation of a sortable table than jQuery. For example, [angular-tablesort](http://mattiash.github.io/angular-tablesort/) which raises events that you can handle when the table is sorted.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I was only using sortable explicitly to allow the user to rearrange the table by clicking and dragging the rows around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make the table sortable, you can define a callback when the table is changed. For example in your case,

```
$("tbody").sortable({
  change: function(event, ui) {
    //Do something, probably with these properties:
    //ui.item (the jQuery object of the item being dragged)
    //ui.position (the new position of the item as {top, left})
    //ui.originalPosition (the original position of the item as {top, left})
  }
});
```

Comment: Would this need to be in a seperate .js file, or would it be in `<script>` tags in the HTML?

Comment: You mentioned you were already using the `sortable` function. As you can see, this is the same function but with a 'change' event.

Comment: This does it as soon as it starts to change though, not once the change is done. How would you do it for the latter?